# How to add buttons to the JFace ErrorDialog

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, jface

I'm trying to add a "Cancel" button to this popup dialog, the dialog basically just gives the user some info and allows them to hit Yes or view details. The problem is that there is no Cancel button and I would like to add one.

The dialog is a JFace `ErrorDialog` which uses a premade `MultiStatus` to display the error message. The dialog opens and gives an OK button or a Cancel button. Is there anyway to directly manipulate how the dialog creates buttons or some other method I could use to change how it looks? Any help is appreciated!

```
if (ErrorDialog.openError(shell, 
    Messages.ConsistencyAction_confirm_dialog_title, null,
    multiStatus, IStatus.WARNING) != Window.OK) {
    return;
}
```

This is the dialog I'm trying to change. This is basically checking to make sure that someone presses ok, if they don't then you exit. You can exit it by hitting the red X in the corner but it'd be less confusing to have a button.

Comment: Can you show us your code for displaying the dialog as it is not really clear which dialog you are using at present.

Comment: added the code I was talking about

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can extend the `ErrorDialog` class so that you can override the `createButtonsForButtonBar` method.

For example this is from the Eclipse p2 install plugin:

```
public class OkCancelErrorDialog extends ErrorDialog {

    public OkCancelErrorDialog(Shell parentShell, String dialogTitle, String message, IStatus status, int displayMask) {
        super(parentShell, dialogTitle, message, status, displayMask);
    }

    @Override
    protected void createButtonsForButtonBar(Composite parent) {
        // create OK, Cancel and Details buttons
        createButton(parent, IDialogConstants.OK_ID, IDialogConstants.OK_LABEL, true);
        createButton(parent, IDialogConstants.CANCEL_ID, IDialogConstants.CANCEL_LABEL, true);
        createDetailsButton(parent);
    }
}
```

With this you can't use the static `ErrorDialog.openError` method, instead you will have to do something like:

```
OkCancelErrorDialog dialog = new OkCancelErrorDialog(shell, Messages.ConsistencyAction_confirm_dialog_title, null, multiStatus, IStatus.WARNING);
```